# NOT NULL constraint failed: loginpage_location.org_id

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and learning to get a hang of the entire thing. I am not really sure why the problem is existing.

I have looked up in a few stackoverflow questions, but me being a novice, i couldn't understand much from the explanation. I would like to know the 'why' alongwith the 'how' if possible.

views.py

```
def orgdataentry(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        orgdataform = OrgDataEntryForm(data=request.POST or None)
        orglocform = OrgLocEntryForm(data=request.POST or None)
        if orgdataform.is_valid() and orglocform.is_valid():
            #fs = orgdataform.save(commit=False)
            #fs.user = request.user
            orgdataform.save()

            orglocform.org = request.POST['org_name']
            #fs = orglocform.save(commit=False)
            #fs.user = request.user
            orglocform.save()

            return HttpResponse('Success')
        else:
            return render(request, 'org_login/dataentry.html', {'orgdataform': orgdataform, 'orglocform': orglocform})

    else:
        return redirect('login')
```

I have tried running the code with the commented code lines as well but no luck

forms.py

```
class OrgDataEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        db_table = 'Organization Details'
        fields = '__all__'


class OrgLocEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        db_table = 'Organization Locations'
        exclude = ['org']
```

And models.py

```
class OrgType(models.Model):

    org_type_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org_external = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    org_sector = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', verbose_name='Sector')
    org_type_des = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Sector Description')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org_sector


class Organization(models.Model):

    org_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', verbose_name='Company Name')
    org_type = models.ForeignKey(OrgType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Company Type')
    org_inc_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Incorporation Date', help_text='Please specify in DD/MM/YYYY format')
    org_email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Email ID')
    org_contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', verbose_name='Contact Number')
    org_esc_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Escalation Number')
    org_hq = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', verbose_name='Main Office City')
    org_des = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Company Description')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org_name


class Location(models.Model):

    loc_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Company Name')
    addline1 = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Address Line 1')
    addline2 = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Address Line 2')
    addline3 = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Address Line 3')
    org_country = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', verbose_name='Country')
    org_state = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', verbose_name='State')
    org_city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', verbose_name='City')
    org_zip = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', verbose_name='Pin-code')
    org_loc_des = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Location Description')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.org.org_name + ': ' + self.org_city
```

I hope this might be the only issue and if done, it would be great. The orgdataform is being saved and the issue is while saving the orglocform.

Alright, now let me clear myself. For obvious reasons, I don't wish for the company to other clients, and in order to implement that, I need to assign to what is the foreign key of location related to. If possible, please let me know that for this might actually solve this problem since, I am want the answer to this particular thing only.

Comment: You need to reduce this "code dump" to the smallest example possible that reproduces your problem. Whenever you have a python issue with an exception, you need to provide the full traceback (it contains vital information). If you've done anything to debug the issue yourself (e.g. printing `request.POST` in your view), you should include what you've done and the results as well.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't answer the question since you didn't provide all relevant informations, but from a quick look at your code the issue is very certainly here:

```
orglocform.org = request.POST['org_name']
orglocform.save()
```

This is wrong on two points: first, setting `orglocform.org` will not do anything useful (it just sets a totally useless `.org` attribute on the form instance itself, which won't do anything with it), and then what you set it to (`request.POST['org_name']`) is a string when what the `Location` model wants is an `Organization` instance (also and FWIW `request.POST['org_name']` is an unsanitized user input, so it's actually a good thing it's not used by the form).

Your `Location` model requires an `Organization` instance so what you want here is to first create the  `Organization` *and keep a reference to it*, then retrieve the partially initialized but yet unsaved `Location` instance, set its `org` field to the newly created `Organization` instance and (finally) save it:

```
def orgdataentry(request):    
    # let's get rid of this first:
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')


    if request.method == "POST":
        orgdataform = OrgDataEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        orglocform = OrgLocEntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if orgdataform.is_valid() and orglocform.is_valid():
            # create the Organization and keep a reference
            org = orgdataform.save()
            # retrieve the (yet incomplete and unsaved) Location (cf the `commit=False` argument)
            loc =  orglocform.save(commit=False)
            # set the Location's org and save the whole thing
            loc.org = org
            loc.save()

            return HttpResponse('Success')

   else:
        orgdataform = OrgDataEntryForm()
        orglocform = OrgLocEntryForm()


   return render(request, 'org_login/dataentry.html', {'orgdataform': orgdataform, 'orglocform': orglocform})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such quick reply and thanks for explaining it well. Was stuck on it for long time. This might seem like a weird question but how can I save the entry into a specific db since the attribute 'using' of save works with a Model object and not that of ModelForm. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: @ShabbirKhandwala glad my answer could help - and feel free to accept and/or upvote it then). wrt/ multi-db, there are quite a few informations available in the fine manual - the most obvious option being to write a router that will select the appropriate db for a given record. But if you _really_ want to override this at the view level, just re-read the above code and the fine manual's chapter on ModelForm.save (hint: why do you thing I passed `commit=False` in the `orglocform.save()` call ?)